# knitr has stopped outputting plots

Tags: r, knitr

I recently ran into a problem with knitr in R, where it suddenly stopped making plots. It does not report any problems, issues. It just that chunk that makes a plot (native R or ggplot2) does nothing. The chunk is evaluated, but somehow regarded as a chunk without R code.

I've reduced the problem to a minimal example, but have no idea what has gone wrong. The entire file can be found at http://pastebin.com/pJUYjkxd and has this single chunk. Should be pretty straightforward?

```
<<mas11,dev='png'>>=
plot(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
@
```

But knitting it produces the following output (with R version 2.14.1):

```
Rscript --vanilla  -e "library(knitr); knit('test.dev.2.Rnw');"


processing file: test.dev.2.Rnw
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                      |  67%
label: mas11 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ dev: chr "png"

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: /home/stefan/Repos/manuscript1/datahandling/test.dev.2.tex
```

And the final pdf-file is [image] 
where you can see the chunk has been echoed.

I have no idea how to resolve this problem!
Kindly help.

**Update**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_DK.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_DK.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_0.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.2   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.6    plyr_1.8       stringr_0.6.1 
[6] tools_2.14.1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. `library(knitr); sessionInfo()` please!

Comment: Try using `fig=TRUE` and the various options in the chunk options instead of manually inserting the \begin{figure} stuff.

Comment: @Dason - I cannot find any documentation for `fig=TRUE` in http://yihui.name/knitr/options; there are a lot of variants (''fig.align'', etc.).

Comment: @MrGumble You are right that there is no `fig=TRUE` in knitr now; that is an option only for the compatibility purpose with Sweave in the very early days. As I said, please post session info.

Comment: Please see knitr FAQ 1: http://bit.ly/knitr-faq

Comment: Thank you @Yihui I was also stupefied to see that my knitr package was so outdated. But my problem also arises on another workstation that has knitr 1.1 - but recreating the issue is difficult, as it is a bit spurious.

Answer (score -2):

fig=TRUE in "<<>>="worked for me!

The problem was in "**<>=**"
from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{A Minimal Example}
\author{Yihui Xie}
\maketitle
We examine the relationship between speed and stopping
distance using a linear regression model:
$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$.
<<model, fig.width=4, fig.height=3, fig.align='center'>>=
par(mar = c(4, 4, 1, 1), mgp = c(2, 1, 0), cex = 0.8)
plot(cars, pch = 20, col = 'darkgray')
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
abline(fit, lwd = 2)
@
The slope of a simple linear regression is
\Sexpr{coef(fit)[2]}.
\end{document}
```

Xie, Yihui (2013-09-09). Dynamic Documents with R and knitr (Chapman & Hall/CRC The R Series) (Page 13). Taylor and Francis CRC ebook account. Kindle Edition.

Best,

Roberto